# how to use unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestIgnore("ignored") with specflow and Nunit

Tags: specflow

I am trying to use `unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestIgnore("ignored")` in [BeforeScenario] in my hooks file as I found the references where some people are using it successfully .

[How to programmatically ignore some acceptance tests using TechTalk.SpecFlow and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12586040/)

https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2059#issuecomment-707788460

https://groups.google.com/g/specflow/c/GcbBOF1xEgs/m/Kvf0NdnDCwAJ

but when I try to do the same I am getting exception [image]and control moves to my scenario which should be ignored. Am I missing something in my code?

```
[BeforeScenario]
        public void Initialize() {
            tag = _testrailHelper.GetTestcaseId(_scenarioContext);
            TestCaseId = tag.Replace("C", "");
            if (resultstotr) {
                if (testTobeExecuted.Contains(TestCaseId)){
                execute test
                } else {
                    
                    var unitTestRuntimeProvider = (IUnitTestRuntimeProvider)
                    _scenarioContext.GetBindingInstance((typeof(IUnitTestRuntimeProvider)));
                    unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestIgnore("ignored");
}
```

I even tried to use `Assert.Ignore()` instead of `unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestIgnore("ignored")` but with same output

Comment: It doesn't look like SpecFlow will skip the scenario in a hook. The examples I've seen skip the scenario in a step definition.

Comment: The references I have added ,there it was mentioned that people were able to use it sucessfully in hooks

Comment: Is the test failing? To be honest, things like `Assert.Ignore` are implemented as exceptions. This seems like expected behavior when debugging the test, but I would expect the test runner to properly catch that exception and mark the test "ignored".

Comment: For me its not working in Stepdef as well. How to use ?, Can you share some example.?
If I implement this in the def of first step of scenario then will it skip whole scenario?

Comment: Any working example would be helpful

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the code for the step definition? We need a [repro] before we can answer your question.

Comment: It seems to be working within the Hooks. but Somehow The number is not correct .
 I am executing only 2 tests from my suit but Count is displayed as
Total tests: 292
     Passed: 2
     Failed: 9
    Skipped: 281
 Total time: 1.4968 Minutes